# C# joining strings after a specific character

Tags: c#

I have a string and would like to know how I can split the values into separate variables

```
string c = "1237^^^John^^^Abraham^^Dr";
```

I would like to put Dr. John Abraham into one variable.

```
String name = "Dr. John Abraham";
```

Would be grateful for advice on this. I tried the indexof but couldn't figure out correctly.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking. Perhaps you should use `string.Split` to split on `^`? Once you've got the values independently, joining some of them together shouldn't be too hard. I would definitely separate the two tasks (splitting vs joining) so that you can focus on just *one* part in the question.

Comment: How would anybody know, that the `Dr` belongs to the front of the string and how would the computer know to append a `.` to it?

Comment: Please edit the question and add **example input** and the **desired output** - we could of course write the code to transform `"1237^^^John^^^Abraham^^^Dr"` to `"Dr. John Abraham"` but I am sure this is not the only string you want to transform, right?`

Comment: Is this part of a HL7 message? If yes, I would recommend using a framework to process these messages. We are using [Merge HL7 Toolkit](http://www.merge.com/Solutions/Toolkits/Merge-HL7-Toolkit.aspx) in our project.

Comment: please define rules for the order of the output string. Where did the `.` in `Dr.` come from? how is this supposed to work for other strings?

Comment: Yes, this is part of an HL7 message. Using C# to parse the messages and build the message.

Comment: Thank You guys, I used the split function, and was able to get the values. It was a start, and Jamiec's solution benefited .

Comment: If this is a well known thing (HL7) youre far better off using a library than rolling your own parser!

Comment: I agree with Jamiec, in the long run using a library will save you A LOT of maintenance compared to a custom parser.

Comment: Have you looked into nHAPI (https://github.com/duaneedwards/nHapi) or FHIR (https://github.com/ewoutkramer/fhir-net-api) ? They seem to offer an object model for HL7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `String.Split` with `^` as the separator and `RemoveEmptyEntries`

```
var input = "1237^^^John^^^Abraham^^Dr";
var split = input.Split(new[]{'^'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1} {2}", split[3], split[1], split[2]);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/HHE60664

Comment: Thank You Jamiec. This is helpful. I was able to get it

Comment: @EricDavid if youve found this correct please vote this as the answer